# Visual Studio 2012 - Clone to other view

Tags: visual-studio

In VS2012 is it possible to have 2 copies of the same file open side by side?

just like Notepad++'s Clone to Other View feature?

Current workaround is to have 2 copies of VS opened with the same solution.

Comment: This of course exists: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsprereleaseannouncements/thread/8fcb2fa4-d8d6-469b-9567-ab7fa0c26509 I was able to find it by looking for `clone view visual studio` on google very **first** result

Comment: Ahh - your google skills are good.  Hopefully this question will help others like me.. Window Menu, New Window.  Put in an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: and it only works in code view